# Get Only Selected Option Attribute of Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have dropdowns that show quantity and price of items. Each `<option>` has their own `data-roomid` attribute. When I select one `<option>`, it also shows all selected `<option>` of other dropdowns due to `querySelectorAll()` (I think). I just want to get only one `data-roomid` attribute when I select an `<option>` from any dropdown. How exactly can I do it?

Here is what I have done and as I said above, it gets every selected `<option>` of each dropdown no matter which dropdown I click.

```js
function sumre() {
 var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms");
 selects.forEach(function(select){
  var roomid = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-roomid");
  alert(roomid);
 });
}
```

```html
<select id="room_length_dropdown_21" class="rooms" onchange="sumre()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option data-roomid="48" value="1" data-price="88">1 ($ 88)</option>
    <option data-roomid="49" value="2" data-price="176">2 ($ 176)</option>
    <option data-roomid="50" value="3" data-price="264">3 ($ 264)</option>
    <option data-roomid="51" value="4" data-price="352">4 ($ 352)</option>
    <option data-roomid="52" value="5" data-price="440">5 ($ 440)</option>
</select>

<select id="room_length_dropdown_23" class="rooms" onchange="sumre()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option data-roomid="58" value="1" data-price="77">1 ($ 77)</option>
    <option data-roomid="59" value="2" data-price="154">2 ($ 154)</option>
    <option data-roomid="60" value="3" data-price="231">3 ($ 231)</option>
    <option data-roomid="61" value="4" data-price="308">4 ($ 308)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: maybe because you use `.forEach`? In jQuery it would be `$('.rooms').eq(0).find('option:selected').data('roomid')`

Comment: Well _you_ are selecting _all_ `.rooms` elements … if you don’t want that, then don’t do it. Instead, access the select element that the event was triggered on _only_. (With this old-school method of attaching event handlers via HTML attributes, you will need to do it like this, `function sumre(selectelement) {…}` and `onchange="sumre(this)"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about to pass "select" object to sumre method?

```js
function sumre(select) {
  var roomid = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-roomid");
  alert(roomid);
}
```

```html
<select id="room_length_dropdown_21" class="rooms" onchange="sumre(this)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option data-roomid="48" value="1" data-price="88">1 ($ 88)</option>
    <option data-roomid="49" value="2" data-price="176">2 ($ 176)</option>
    <option data-roomid="50" value="3" data-price="264">3 ($ 264)</option>
    <option data-roomid="51" value="4" data-price="352">4 ($ 352)</option>
    <option data-roomid="52" value="5" data-price="440">5 ($ 440)</option>
</select>

<select id="room_length_dropdown_23" class="rooms" onchange="sumre(this)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option data-roomid="58" value="1" data-price="77">1 ($ 77)</option>
    <option data-roomid="59" value="2" data-price="154">2 ($ 154)</option>
    <option data-roomid="60" value="3" data-price="231">3 ($ 231)</option>
    <option data-roomid="61" value="4" data-price="308">4 ($ 308)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery to simplify my answer**

You can pass `this` to function to know what element you changed:

```js
function sumre(el) {
  var roomId = $('option:selected', el).data('roomid');

  alert(roomId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="room_length_dropdown_21" class="rooms" onchange="sumre(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option data-roomid="48" value="1" data-price="88">1 ($ 88)</option>
  <option data-roomid="49" value="2" data-price="176">2 ($ 176)</option>
  <option data-roomid="50" value="3" data-price="264">3 ($ 264)</option>
  <option data-roomid="51" value="4" data-price="352">4 ($ 352)</option>
  <option data-roomid="52" value="5" data-price="440">5 ($ 440)</option>
</select>

<select id="room_length_dropdown_23" class="rooms" onchange="sumre(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option data-roomid="58" value="1" data-price="77">1 ($ 77)</option>
  <option data-roomid="59" value="2" data-price="154">2 ($ 154)</option>
  <option data-roomid="60" value="3" data-price="231">3 ($ 231)</option>
  <option data-roomid="61" value="4" data-price="308">4 ($ 308)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a good answer for JQuery. I am using another Javascript library instead of JQuery. I can't give +1 due to low rep